# How to keep locator at the centre of parents when deleting parent constraint in python

Tags: python, maya

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

sel = cmds.ls(sl = True)
cmds.spaceLocator(n = 'driver')
for i in sel:
    cmds.parentConstraint(i, 'driver', n = 'delPs', mo = False)
#until this line, the 'driver' keeps its position at the centre of i
    cmds.delete('delPs')
#after this line, the 'driver' moves to the pivot point of the last item on the selection.
```

I'm trying to keep locator(driver) at the centre of the selected objects after delete constraint node.Can I get some advise?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do. Do you want your locator at the center of everything ? Do you want one locator at the center of each object ? At the moment your script is putting the locator at the center of the last object

Answer (score 0):

im not sure to understand your problem but here is some solutions, hope one will help you, im using math instead of constraint

```
from __future__ import division
import maya.cmds as cmds

# =========================
#just to illustrate an exemple selection of 10 sphere combined
import random
psph = [cmds.polySphere()[0] for i in range(4)]
for i in psph:
    cmds.setAttr(i+'.t', random.uniform(0.0, 10), random.uniform(0.0, 10), random.uniform(0.0, 10))
# sph_comb = cmds.polyUnite(psph)
cmds.delete(psph , ch=True)
# ===============================

def getCentroid(sel):

    obj = cmds.ls(sel, o=True)
    sel = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(sel, tv=True)
    sel = cmds.ls(sel, flatten=1)

    if len(obj) > 1:
        pos = []
        for s in sel:
            p = cmds.xform(s, q=1, t=1, ws=1)
            pos += p
    else:
        pos = cmds.xform(sel, q=1, t=1, ws=1)
    nb = len(sel)
    myCenter = sum(pos[0::3]) / nb, sum(pos[1::3]) / nb, sum(pos[2::3]) / nb

    return myCenter

# example for each sphere
sel= cmds.ls(psph)
for i in sel:
    loc = cmds.spaceLocator(n = 'driver')[0]
    coord = getCentroid(i)
    cmds.setAttr(loc+'.t', *coord)

# for only one at the center of all sphres
sel= cmds.ls(psph)
coord = getCentroid(sel)
loc = cmds.spaceLocator()[0]
cmds.setAttr(loc+'.t', *coord)
```

## EDIT : fix some code issue on my function getCentroid because xform can get multiple object